# How can a predefined email be opened with the default email program in Windows?

Tags: windows, email, tcl

I'm searching for a possibility to generate a predefined mail when the user clicks on a button in a tcl/Tk program. Up to now I'm using the `mailto`-protocol, but as the predefined message may have a long body, the message may be cut at some point. Thus, this is no real solution.

All alternatives I found up to now have some drawbacks. So, is there a possibility which meets following requests?

- Open *default mail program*, which may be a proprietary one (not only the standard ones like Outlook or Thunderbird...)
- Create (and open) *predefined message* with either much text or alternatively an attachment
- Should work on at least *Windows XP* until current versions (*Windows 10*) and also with very *limited user rights*
- Must be possible to implement with *tcl* or *C*

It would be no solution to just send a Mail in the background, as it should be really transparent what happens and which information is send...
(I know there are already many questions about similar topics, but I haven't found a solution which worked for me.)

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to automate sending mails on Windows via [`tcom`](http://wiki.tcl-lang.org/tcom) by using the [`CDO.Message` COM object](http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm).

That's a Windows-only solution.

A cross-platform solution which should work everywhere is using the package [`mime`](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/mime/mime.html) to construct the message and [`smtp`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/mime/smtp.html) to send it.  Both are part of "the standard Tcl library", `tcllib`, available on any sensible system which has Tcl packaged.

As to

> It would be no solution to just send a Mail in the background, as it should be really transparent what happens and which information is send...

I failed to parse it. Could you may be try to reformulate?

---

*Update:*

Well, OK, after re-reading the title I think I completely fail to understand the essense of the question.

If everything what's needed is opening a e-mail *message* — as in "a file with MIME-formatted text representing an e-mail message", — I think that's hardly possible because a "default program to handle e-mails" is specified for URIs having the `mailto` scheme.

If what's needed is to spawn a default mail client on Windows asking it to open a window to let the use compose an e-mail message destined to the predefined address, the you can use

```
exec [list rundll32.exe uri.dll,FileProtocolHandler "malto:$addr"]
```

where the `addr` variable contains the recipient's e-mail address.

The `mailto:` URIs allow specifying the message body (and may be that's what you're currently using) but they (rightfully) do not allow specifying a file name to interpret as a message, so there appears to be no way to open a mail client with a pre-made message.

---

*Update #2:*

OK, so may be I finally got what did you mean by saying "should be really transparent...".  You mean the user has to see with their own eyes what will be sent, right?  But what's wrong with just emulating an e-mail client by presenting the user with a dialog window showing which will be sent?  This is used by every software product I have seen which had a similar feature. Various Microsoft and Mozilla products come to mind as the most visible examples.  They just offer you a dialog box to browse what will be sent.

Note that even if the user saw "what will be sent" in a true mail client and hit "Send" with their own hand, nothing prevents *any* host among those which will be handling this message (usually two at least) from modifying it unless it was a cryptographically signed message (in S/MIME format).

Are you sure you want to go that far?

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply. But you were right with your updates. Currently I'm using some sort of the mailto-protocol like the one you proposed in your first update, more precisely: `eval exec [auto_execok start] $mailto` with a typical mailto string in the `$mailto`. With the "predefined message" I meant, that the message already includes a title, to, cc, body,... In my mailto string all this is included. But as the body may be very long, the text may get cut off. Therefore I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: To your *Update #2*: As the user may have sensitive data in our program, the question is, if he would trust a given dialog. He could get worried, if there is really no other information used in the program, which will be sent, and the chance, that he may abort the transmission will rise. By opening his default mail client, the sensitive data of our program is decoupled of the e-mail transmission.

Comment: @quarenjo, how about letting the user save the information to a file of their choice (using a dialog we've discussed), open the mail client via a `mailto:` URI and ask the client to review and attach the file there? That's half-assed but better  than nothing.

Comment: As it seems that there is no easy solution to my problem, this may be a compromise. I thought the same and now pop up a window if the message is longer than a preset length and ask the user to copy the text for the message body to the mail, which is generated by the `mailto:` Nevertheless, I still hope, I'll find a better solution.